# How do I use Ruby refinements inside Rails Controller/Action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinements

If I try outside the controller it works:

```
using ParamsExtension
class ApplicationController
```

If I try inside the controller or an action it does not work:

```
class ApplicationController
using ParamsExtension
```

It throws 'undefined method `using'.

I read this article and the author is using it inside a class: [timelessrepo.com/refinements-in-ruby](http://timelessrepo.com/refinements-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this article](https://blog.codeship.com/ruby-refinements/), refinements within classes are only  available on 2.3 and up.

Answer (score 1):

I read the following from the documentation:

> You may only activate refinements at top-level, not inside any class,
>   module or method scope. You may activate refinements in a string
>   passed to Kernel#eval that is evaluated at top-level. Refinements are
>   active until the end of the file or the end of the eval string,
>   respectively.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html

Comment: Interesting, but I read this article, the author is using it inside a class: http://timelessrepo.com/refinements-in-ruby

Comment: What version of ruby are you using? In Ruby 2.0, the docs aren't as explicit about where the 'using' clause may be placed. Here are the 2.0 docs: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html

Comment: I'm using 2.0.0. I just read the doc in your comment and there is an example of 'using' inside a class: "You may also activate refinements in a class or module definition, in which case the refinements are activated from the point where using is called to the end of the class or module definition:"